# Filter an empty array from a parent array

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

How can I completely remove an empty array from a parent array, before adding a new element.

I have a structure that looks like this

```
var parentArray = [ ['123', '345'], [], ['12'] ]
```

I want to remove array at index 1 before adding a new array.

I have tried this but it doesn't remove it:

```
parentArray.filter((array, index) => {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        parentArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
})
parentArray.push(['435']);

console.log(parentArray);  //Still give  [["123", "345"], [], ["12"]]
```

Comment: did u try ```_.filter```

Comment: Don't try to mutate an array while iterating over it, instead *use* the `.filter` by returning a truthy/falsey value based on whether you want the item to be included or not (no need for lodash)

Comment: try `_.map`..return `array.length > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mutate your array in the filter method.
The callback function should return true if you want to keep the item, false if not.

```
const parentArray = [['123', '345'], [], ['12']];

const filteredArray = parentArray.filter( item => item.length !== 0);

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need lodash or 3rd part libraries, here is what actually you needed,

```js
var numbers = [ ['123', '345'], [], ['12'] ]

result = numbers.filter(x => x.length > 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I want to mention that technically, you can also shorten the predicate to `x => x.length` since zero would be falsey and everything else truthy. However, I prefer the more explicit `> 0` (or `!= 0`) as it's not much longer and it makes things ever so slightly clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter) for that:

```
parentArray = _.filter(parentArray, function (array) {
    return array.length > 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code keeps the items which are not empty and stores them inside result.

```
const result = _.filter(parentArray, (item, i) => {
  return !_.isEmpty(item);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer came in low quality post. Add some explanation even though code is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First of all as said above don't mutate any iterable while iterating through it.
and `Array.filter` returns a new array based on the condition given and it won't change the array on which it is being called.
if you want to keep the original parentArray and create a new array without the empty arrays in the parrentArray then do the following

```
let parentArray2 = parentArray.filter(e=>e.length !== 0)
```

this will give you the new array referenced by `parentArray2` which will be
`[ [ '123', '345' ], [ '12' ] ]`
and `parentArray` remains as it is and then you can push a new array into `parentArray2`

if you don't want to retain the original `parentArray` then do the following
`parentArray = parentArray.filter(e=>e.length !== 0)`
the parent array will be initialized with a new array `[ [ '123', '345' ], [ '12' ] ]`
and then you can push any element are array or object into the `parentArray`

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject) with [`_.isEmpty()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEmpty).

Reject removes an item if the predicate returns `true`, and isEmpty returns `true` for empty arrays.

```js
var parentArray = [ ['123', '345'], [], ['12'] ]

var result = _.reject(parentArray, _.isEmpty)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Without lodash, you can use `Array.filter()`, and just return the `length`. Because `0` is falsy, and the item would be removed:

```js
const numbers = [ ['123', '345'], [], ['12'] ]

const result = numbers.filter(o => o.length)

console.log(result)
```